# Logstash plugin for CW Metrics: cannot collect CPUUtilization of autoscaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, logstash

I'm trying to collect CloudWatch metrics data using Logstash.
I have successfully installed the plugin, but I'm unable to collect the ,metrics data from about CPUUtilization of an autoscaling group.

Here's the input I have configured:

```
cloudwatch {
    access_key_id => "${PROD_KEY_ENV}"
    secret_access_key => "${PROD_SECRET_KEY_ENV}"
    type => "prod"
    tags => ["CWMetrics"]
    namespace => "AWS/EC2"
    metrics => ["CPUUtilization"]
    filters => {"AutoScalingGroupName" => "name_of_asg"}
    period => 60
    statistics => ["Average"]
    region => "eu-central-1"
  }
```

Logstash correctly starts and correctly collects data (also other CW metrics data I have configured), but for the input right above I got the following error:

```
Error: The filter 'AutoScalingGroupName' is invalid
```

Can you please help me?

Thank you,

Luca

Comment: The filter is passed to the aws api and it needs to be supported by the API, this is explained in the [input documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-cloudwatch.html#plugins-inputs-cloudwatch-filters). From the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/APIReference/API_Filter.html) maybe you need to use it as `auto-scaling-group` or create and add a tag and filter using this tag.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, I continue to get the same error if I use "auto-scaling-group" as filter. Instead of using a tag, do you think there are other possibilities?